# Pandas - Merging rows with time difference (When datetime is index)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, timestamp

I have found some tasks to do, to develop myself more with Pandas, but I found some unexpected errors in the data files I used. And actually wanted to fix it by myself, but I have no idea how.

Basically I have an excel file, with columns - PayType, Money, Date. In the column of PayType, I have 4 different types of payment. Car rent payment, car service fee payment, and 2 more which are not important. Basically, on every entry of car rent payment, there is an automatic service fee deduction, which happens at the exactly same time. I used the Pivot table and divided PayTypes as columns, as I wanted to count the percentage of these fees.

Before Pivot Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFodU.png)

Time difference example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ho8f.png)

After Pivot Table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPnRD.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

 df = pd.read_excel ('C:/Data.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1',
                usecols = ['PayType', 'Money', 'Date'])

 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:$M:%S.%f')

 df = df.pivot_table(index = ['Date'],
                columns = ['PayType']).fillna(0)

 df = pd.merge_asof(df['Money', 'serviceFee'], df['Money', 'carRenting'], on = 'Date', tolerance = 
      pd.Timedelta('2s'))

 df['Percentage'] = df['Money','serviceFee'] / df['Money','carRenting'] * 100
 df['Percentage'] = df['Percentage'].abs()

 df['Charges'] = np.where(df['Percentage'].notna(), np.where(df['Percentage'] > 26, 'Overcharge - 
                 30%', 'Fixed - 25%'), 'Null')


 df.to_excel("Finale123.xlsx")
```

So in the Pivot table, entries for renting the car and fee payments almost all of them happened at the same moment, so their time is equal and they are in one row. But there are few mistakes, where time is different for carrenting and feepayment just for 1 or 2 seconds. Because of this time difference, they are divided into 2 different rows.

I tried to use merge_asof, but it didn't work.

How can I merge 2 rows, which have different times (by 2 seconds max) and also this time column (date) is the actual index for the pivot table.

Comment: Can you display your input and output samples?

Comment: @Johnny Sure, I'll add now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I needed to merge time series data of multiple sensors. The time interval of the sensor measurements are 5 seconds. The time format is yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss. To do the merge, I also needed to sort the column used for the merge.

```
sensors_livingroom = load(filename_livingroom)
sensors_bedroom = load(filename_bedroom)

sensors_livingroom = sensors_livingroom.set_index("time")
sensors_bedroom = sensors_bedroom.set_index("time")

sensors_livingroom.index = pd.to_datetime(sensors_livingroom.index, dayfirst=True)
sensors_bedroom.index = pd.to_datetime(sensors_bedroom.index, dayfirst=True)

sensors_livingroom.sort_index(inplace=True)
sensors_bedroom.sort_index(inplace=True)

sensors = pd.merge_asof(sensors_bedroom, sensors_livingroom, on='time', direction="nearest")
```

In my case I wanted to merge to the nearest time value so I set the parameter direction to nearest. In your case, it seems that the time of one dataframe will always be smaller that the time of the other, so it may be better to set direction parameter to forward or backward. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html